# How to get the values of the parameters in a method with Reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

Using `MethodBase`, is it possible to get the parameters and their values of the method that's being called?

To be specific, I'm trying to use reflection to create Cache keys. As each method and its parameter list is unique, I thought it'd be ideal to use this as the key. This is what I'm doing:

```
    public List<Company> GetCompanies(string city)
    {
        string key = GetCacheKey();

        var companies = _cachingService.GetCacheItem(key);
        if (null == company)
        {
            companies = _companyRepository.GetCompaniesByCity(city);
            AddCacheItem(key, companies);
        }

        return (List<Company>)companies;
    }

    public List<Company> GetCompanies(string city, int size)
    {
        string key = GetCacheKey();

        var companies = _cachingService.GetCacheItem(key);
        if (null == company)
        {
            companies = _companyRepository.GetCompaniesByCityAndSize(city, size);
            AddCacheItem(key, companies);
        }

        return (List<Company>)companies;
    }
```

Where `GetCacheKey()` is defined (roughly) as:

```
    public string GetCacheKey()
    {
        StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
        MethodBase methodBase = stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod();
        string name = methodBase.DeclaringType.FullName;

        // get values of each parameter and append to a string
        string parameterVals = // How can I get the param values?

        return name + parameterVals;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to use reflection? In the place where you use your `GetCacheKey` method you know the values of the parameters. You can just specify them:

```
public string GetCacheKey(params object[] parameters)
```

And use like this:

```
public List<Company> GetCompanies(string city)
{
    string key = GetCacheKey(city);
    ...
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, this requires that I have to write the name of each parameter as a parameter of `GetCacheKey()` every time. I'd like to avoid that if I could. If I could get the values dynamically it'd save me a lot of typing.

Comment: @DaveDev: I see your point. Just remember that passing parameters explicitly is much faster than using reflections.

Answer (score 0):

this is a great sample for getting parameters from a method:

```
 public static string GetParamName(System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, int index)
{
    string retVal = string.Empty;
    if (method != null && method.GetParameters().Length > index)
        retVal = method.GetParameters()[index].Name;
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: I think he wants to get the **values** of the parameters... much more difficult... (and unnecessary)

Comment: Bradley is correct - I want the values. However, I don't think it's entirely unnecessary. If I can get the values dynamically, I don't need to add the parameters to `GetCacheKey()` as Andrew has shown in his example above.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for the same answer right.  Besides reflection you can write an Aspect in PostSharp.  This will cut any performance impact of using reflection and won't violate any substitution principles.